# Updating a df column by another column's minimum value from current row onwards

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df that looks like this:

```
#Output: 
    A     B
0   500   Nan
1   800   Nan
2   700   Nan
3   650   Nan
4   800   Nan
5   780   Nan
6   750   Nan
```

I want to populate column B with (Minimum A from current row till end).

Desired Result:

```
#Output: 
    A     B
0   500   500
1   800   650
2   700   650
3   650   650
4   800   750
5   780   750
6   750   750
```

the following tried method gets the minimum of all A's values, I need to somehow specify the row in there.

```
df['B'] = df['A'].min()
```

Any ideas/solutions are appreciated. thank you for you time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the reversed cumulative minimum for that only-looking ahead behaviour:

```py
df["B"] = df.loc[::-1, "A"].cummin()
```

to get

```py
>>> df
     A    B
0  500  500
1  800  650
2  700  650
3  650  650
4  800  750
5  780  750
6  750  750
```

Comment: No idea what that [::-1] does and it's making a knot in brain, but the code works and gets the job done. thanks a lot.